# Flying AKL - LHR with layover in LAX, do I have to go through passport control?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, lax

I am flying AKL-LHR with a stopover at LAX. Does the Tom Bradley International Terminal (TBIT) force you to go through passport control (and thus, security) if you are connecting to another international flight or am I able to stay in the TBIT without clearing passport control since I am not actually staying in America?

EDIT: I didn't include that I am an American and wouldn't need a visa to enter, which is why I thought the suggested duplicate didn't directly apply. So - lack of clarity on my part. I'll accept the duplicate question hat of shame.

Comment: The short answer is yes. It is impossible to transit the United States without being admitted to the United States.

Comment: @choster "Yes" isn't a very good answer to the question "Is it possible to do X or do I have to do the opposite of X?" Good job you gave the longer answer, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Flying AKL - LHR with layover in LAX, do I have to go through passport control?" = Yes, and the response was only provided as a courtesy in the first place.

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought the question was a bit different than the visa question then I realized the important thing I didn't mention is that I'm American and I don't need a visa to come home. I understand why marked as dup, though. Thanks, @choster, for the answer.

Comment: @choster Touche.